# Error en Sencha Themer

Tags: extjs, sencha

Al crear un nuevo theme o al abrir alguno dentro de mi workspace, la aplicación se cae con el siguiente error

> Error: Directory ext-7.1.0.46/ does not exist.
>       at SenchaCmd._closeHandler (/Users/maxi/bin/Sencha/Themer/1_3_7/Sencha
>   Themer.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/sencha-cmd/index.js:236:32)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

Adjunto el archivo workspace.json

```
{
    "apps": [
        "apps/test"
    ],
    "frameworks": {
        "ext": {
            "path": "ext",
            "version": "7.1.0.46"
        }
    },
    "build": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/build"
    },
    "packages": {
        "dir": "${workspace.dir}/packages/local,${workspace.dir}/packages",
        "extract": "${workspace.dir}/packages/remote"
    },
    "name": "Sencha7",
    "tests": {
        "path": "test/project.json"
    }
}
```

El cual se condice con la estructura de directorios de mi workspace, mientras que el SDK se encuentra en bajo la orbita de mi *home*

Agradezco sus comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré la solución a mi problema, lo publico por si alguien más se le ha ocurrido.
El origen del problema en realidad es el Sencha Command. Primero mediante el siguiente comando se puede revisar algunas configuraciones

```
sencha diag show-props
```

De allí me doy cuenta que el path al directorio donde tengo mi versión del SDK es incorrecto. Esta configuración tiene dos fuentes:

/Users/*user*/.sencha/cmd/sencha.cfg, desde aquí se debe cambiar este path 
/Users/*user*/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.1.0.15/sencha.cfg desde donde se puede modificar otras configuraciones.

Espero les sirva. Saludos